# Asp.NET MvcHtmlString and ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression to AspNetCore?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

How to convert this code to AspNetCore

```
public static MvcHtmlString ChqLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
            string resolvedLabelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName;
            if (metadata.IsRequired)
            {
                resolvedLabelText += "*";
            }
            return LabelExtensions.LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(html, expression, resolvedLabelText, htmlAttributes);
        }
```

I know that I can use now instead of `MvcHtmlString` just `HtmlString`

What to do with

```
ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression
```

I couldn't find any alternative ...

Comment: Your title is misleading as it has nothing to do with the question you actually ask

Comment: I edited the title

Answer (score 30):

Those helpers still exist, but they are buried a little.

```
var modelExplorer = ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData, htmlHelper.MetadataProvider);
```

You can then access the metadata with

```
modelExplorer.Metadata
```

and the model itself with

```
modelExplorer.Model
```

I've got some example code here that uses it for PowerBI Embedded report rendering.

https://blogs.endjin.com/2016/09/how-to-use-power-bi-embedded-with-aspnetcore/

Comment: The internal part of the API is now truly internal and cannot be accessed. We should seek for a better approach.

Answer (score 13):

From the @willDaBeast comment on the other answer, what worked for me was the following code that I provided as a separate answer for better formatting. Although it might not be the recommended practice.

```
ModelExpressionProvider expressionProvider = new ModelExpressionProvider(htmlHelper.MetadataProvider);
var metadata = expressionProvider.CreateModelExpression(htmlHelper.ViewData,expression);
```

Answer (score 7):

In netcore 3.0:

1. Get an instance of `ModelExpressionProvider` from DI
2. Use `CreateModelExpression` method

```c#
var metadata = _modelExpressionProvider.CreateModelExpression(ViewData, expression).Metadata;
```

P.S
In order to extend HtmlHelper, I would suggest another approach:

```c#
 public class CustomHtmlHelper : HtmlHelper, ICustomHtmlHelper 
 {
    // add your extension methods here and in ICustomHtmlHelper
    // _modelExpressionProvider will be part of constructor
    // register implementation in DI
 }
```

and use the new helper in views:

```c#
@inject ICustomHtmlHelper Html
```

Comment: So in an ASP.NET MVC project I would have created a static method in a class like HtmlExtensions.cs which I would have called from an EditorTemplate. Since I need access to Dependency Injection, should I actually consider using a ViewComponent instead (since I can use constructor injection there)?

Comment: You can try htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ModelExpressionProvider>();

Comment: In my example, there is no need to use ViewComponent instead of View. @inject will work with View.

Comment: To get the expression provider while still in a static method I used this:     ModelExpressionProvider expressionProvider = new ModelExpressionProvider(htmlHelper.MetadataProvider);
     var metadata = expressionProvider.CreateModelExpression(htmlHelper.ViewData,expression);

Comment: @willDaBeast although it's obviouslly not recommended approach this is actually answer for me. Still can't get used to get rid of these static extension methods.